# CyanogenMod 7 Stable for Droid

Tags: motorola-droid, cyanogenmod, rom-manager

I'm asking this here because the mods at CyanogenMod's forum seem pretty adamant about people not asking about the status of version seven for the Of Droid.

I understand that CM7 hasn't been released for the Droid because of a few lingering instabilities in the ROM and that the CyanogenMod team is working on getting it to a stable state ASAP.  My question is **will CM7 automatically show up in ROM Manager as a ROM available to download as soon as they mark it as a stable release, or will I have to do something to have ROM Manager manually check for an update?**

If this seems like a fairly entry-level question I apologize, I only ask because I haven't been using ROM Manager long enough to experience an update to the ROM I'm using and don't want to miss out on flashing CM7 as soon as it's up to snuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ROM Manager will auto-load the list of available ROMs, yes.  You'll still have to look in that list and see whether CM is there.